# CONVERT function in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

Can we do following in SQL Server 2005 query with convert function.

```
MaxRegID =  (1).ToString("D5"); // c# code
MaxRegID = 00001
```

convert (1) number with 5 digits in column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - right now, SQL Server doesn't have an equivalent to the `Format` (used in `.ToString()`) in .NET.

You can achieve this with:

```
SELECT RIGHT('00000' + CAST(1 AS VARCHAR(5)), 5)
```

SQL Server 2012 ("Denali") will [introduce a `FORMAT` T-SQL function](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/09/17/sql-server-denali-string-function-format-a-quick-introduction/)

You could also create a general purpose function for this - something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.PadInt(@input INT, @length INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(20)

    DECLARE @Padding VARCHAR(20) 
    SELECT @Padding = REPLICATE('0', @Length)

    SELECT @Result = RIGHT(@Padding + CAST(@Input AS VARCHAR(20)), @Length)
    RETURN @Result
END
```

and call it like this:

```
SELECT dbo.PadInt(1, 5)
```

and get back:

```
00001
```